# Django view: redirect user to template based on schema name (got from URL)

Tags: python, django

I am trying to redirect users to various apps based on their schema name. I have written this so far:

```
def loginUser(request, url):
    
    schema_list1 = ['pierre']
    schema_lsit2 = ['itoiz']

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        t = urlparse(url).netloc
        dbschema = '"' + t.split('.', 1)[0] + '"'
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            login(request, user)
            
           
            if dbschema in schema_list1:
                print('yes')
                redirect = '/upload.html'
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect)
            
            elif dbschema in schema_list2:
                print('yes')
                redirect = '/dash2.html'
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect)
                
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()

    context = {
        'form': form,
        }
    return render(request, 'loginUser.html', context)
```

my problem is that I get the error:

```
TypeError at /loginUser
loginUser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    https://itoiz.exostock.net/loginUser
Django Version: 3.0.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
loginUser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
Exception Location: /home/ubuntu/exo/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response, line 113
```

I am fairly new to django and I am confused about why do i get this error, especially because I used the exact same method somewhere else and it worked fine. I am wondering if someone can see what I am missing. By the way is there another way to get the user's url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to do a poor man's tenant schemas?

if so, use https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas (we've used this for several years, it works fantastic.) There is also this one, https://github.com/django-tenants/django-tenants it's a bit more maintained, but i've never used it -- concept is the same.

Other than that, do this instead:

```
def login_user(request):  # we don't do camel-casing
    
    # I don't know your exact use case, but having this in the view seems wrong..
    schema_list1 = ['pierre']
    schema_lsit2 = ['itoiz']

    # This will be an empty "{}" if it's not a POST, meaning, you don't need the 
    # extra if, it will work in both cases
    form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        dbschema, _, _ = request.get_host().partition('.')
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            login(request, user)
            
            if dbschema in schema_list1:
                print('yes')
                redirect = '/upload.html'
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect)
            elif dbschema in schema_list2:
                print('yes')
                redirect = '/dash2.html'
                return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect)
            else:
                raise Exception('HANDLE THIS!!!')

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'loginUser.html', context)
```

Comment: I am using django-tenant and it works amazing. I simply dont know how to have different templates/features for each tenant so I built different apps, and redirect the tenant to one or the other based on their schema name. LMK if you know a more efficient way to do this!

Comment: @Peyo Oh man, you're asking for trouble. You'll end up with a whole lot of if-else and a nightmare to test. I suggest, if possible, to use the concept of "features", where you don't have to worry about giving tenant1 a specific thing, but since tenant1 has the feature active when show it to them. Cautionary tale: "TRY" to make sure you're not developing for one single tenant, make sure that it works for a good 30% of your clients, otherwise the cost of maintenance/testing is not going to be worth it. I don't know your business model, but Im saying "try".

Comment: As for templates, https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates.html#multitenant-aware-filesystem-template-loader there is a concept of doing `app/templates/<tenant>/` <-- theme away. django-tenant also supports it, a bit differently though.. close enough https://django-tenants.readthedocs.io/en/latest/files.html#configuring-the-static-file-finders

Comment: I see what you mean Javier, thanks for your advices! that's the thing, how do I "show" features to one tenant and another. I can't find anything about it in the docs, or at least I have not comprehended it

Comment: @Peyo you won't find "features" in django-tenant[-schema] that is something we came up with for our product. These features live in the tenant side of the db, and they're either enabled or not (BooleanField) in your code all you do is check if they're active or not: `if Feature.objects.get_by_natural_key('feature_name').enabled:` .. do something. Hope this helps. Ask this question as a different SO question, i'm sure you'll get more ideas from the community. Best of luck

Comment: that gives me a lot of ideas, I am going to try implement that, i think I can achieve something pretty lit using your technique and a little bit of my primary idea. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

When you submit form - you probably send request to ‘loginUser’ without arguments.

Another thing is that you probably don’t need to have URL as an argument, you can simply get it from request:

request.build_absolute_uri()